# inherit attributes in to jsf taglib from the form

Tags: jsf, facelets, taglib

When creating custom facelet components in JSF how can I make the component in my taglib inherit the attributes from the component defined in the UI form? For example my taglib file ST.xhtml has

```
<ui:composition>
<h:inputText id="#{id}" value="#{value.ST.value}"/>   
 </ui:composition>
```

my taglib.xhtml has

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://www.tolven.org/jsf/trim</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>ST</tag-name>
        <source>trim/ST.xhtml</source>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib
```

Now in the JSF page myForm.xhtml, where I want to use this taglib I have

```
<html>
<body>
    <ui:composition>
        <trim:ST id="myID" value="#{myBean.prop}" style="width:50;"/>    
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the attributes defined in the UI form inherited in to taglib component without me explicitly inheriting them. For example now the style attribute in `myForm.xhtml` wouldn't work unless I say `style="#{style}"` in file `ST.xhtml`.